# Is it healthy to permanently rely on wet food products for adult cats?

Tags: cats, diet

Is it healthy to permanently rely on wet food products for adult cats?

It's really difficult for me to prepare foods at home or buy cooked chickens from shops every day, so I am thinking of buying Royal Canin wet food products and making them the main meal for my cat, but I am worried about health issues, especially for long-term feeding habits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All well-known brand cat food is going to have the right balance of nutrition for your kitty.  You don't have to worry about health issues (unless your cat has allergies to certain foods).  Now, if you live in a country where it is difficult to get name brand cat food, you need to talk to your vet about what is the best available.

You *do* have to worry about health issues when you feed your cat people food.  Getting all the nutrition your cat needs with people food is very difficult unless your vet is guiding you every step of the way.   Your kitty will likely be even more healthy if you transfer him/her to a brand cat food.

@Keshlam is exactly right that inside cats have a problem with dehydration.   The wet food helps this issue, since it has a large percentage of water in it.

Your issues with feeding only wet cat food will be...(1) soft stool (that may turn into diarrhea often),(2) ensuring you take up the dish after your kitty eats (just like us, you don't want to leave wet food out all day; the food can degrade and harm your kitty), and (3) teeth problems (also mentioned by Keshlam).

To ease the issues I mention above, I feed my cats dry food during the day and wet food at night.  AND I have a drinking fountain with constant running water for them, which encourages them to drink more...well worth the money.

Just some things to think about.  I wish you and your kitty the best!

Comment: Thank you a lot ... For my country, i found (Royal Canin Rice And Chicken) only in wet foods category.
As i read, it is made for sensitivity control, really i didn't understand what they mean by that, but anyway, the shop told me it's good even if my cat doesn't suffer from any health issues ... could you please advice me about that kind of food ? continue feeding my cat with it ? or stop ? Thanks

Comment: By "sensitivity control", they mean that the food is designed for cats with allergies or food intolerances. It just means that they avoid certain ingredients that may cause problems for some cats. So it is fine to feed your cat that food, even if your cat has no allergies or food intolerance problems.

Comment: @AymAnAbuOmar Would you mind telling me what country you're from?  I have travelled a lot and always feed the stray cats where ever I go.  In some countries, it is difficult to find quality food (not even quality food but just something decent you think will be ok for the cat).  Your vet may be recommending Royal Canin Sensitive food (which *is* a top brand of cat food) because that is the best food you can get in your country.  If this is the case, continue to use it.  Thank you for caring about your cat, so much...and Merry Christmas!

Comment: @KittyConsltant I am syrian but living in Saudi Arabia, honestly, they recommend all Royal Canin products and when i see that kind of food, i took it. We have a lot of brands like whiskas and others but no one as i know recommend it ... honestly, i didn't ask the vet yet but i will very soon. I THINK : MORE YOU PAY, MORE QUALITY YOU GET :)

thank you.

Comment: @AymAnAbuOmar Also be careful with low caloric intake in a wet food diet. Check the calorie counts on the cans and make sure your cat is meeting their requirements each day. Wet food has a very low calorie per mass ratio compared to dry food. Otherwise expect weight loss over time, possibly serious if they aren't eating enough. Btw yes, Royal Canin is great stuff.

Answer (score 3):

My vet would say wet food may be preferable. Paraphrasing: "House cats descend from a desert breed and evolved to get a lot of their moisture from their prey. Dry food is convenient and may be better for their teeth but doesn't give them that, and they may be getting dehydrated as a result--you've seen how awkward it is for cats to drink."

Personally, I'm undecided. My current cats are getting much more wet food and have some obvious dental issues; my previous cat got almost entirely dry food and AFAIK didn't have those same issues... but that may be individual variation rather than evidence, and vets were less good about looking for dental problems then.